# Time picker range validation for appending more than 4 text boxes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, timepicker

I have one text box for asking how many matching schedules are available per day. Based on that I need to get the start time and end time for the entire schedule.

If a user can enter 3 schedules then I need to get three 3 start times and end times. That is working fine but the problem is I need to avoid conflicting times.

for example

> 1. schedule time : start time is 9:00 but end time is 8:30 (time conflict)
> 2. schedule 1 is 9:30 to 12:30 and schedule 2 is 10:30 to 13:30 (schedule conflict)

These are the conflicts I need to avoid, someone help me please.

I tried in this sample click button and it is shown:

http://jsbin.com/lixig/8/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to determine whether two numeric ranges overlap. It accepts two arrays of the form `[start, end]`.

```
function rangesOverlap(range1, range2) {
  return range1[1] > range2[0] && range2[1] > range1[0];
}
```

Assuming you have an array of ranges, to determine that none overlap:

```
function noneOverlap(ranges) {
  var untestedRanges = ranges.slice();
  return ranges.every(function(range1) {
    untestedRanges.shift();
    return untestedRanges.every(function(range2) {
      return ! rangesOverlap(range1, range2);
    });
  });
}
```

For example:

```
noneOverlap([[0,1],[0,2]]) // => false
noneOverlap([[0,1],[2,3]]) // => true
```

Comment: Friend are show in fiddle because i cannot understand ur code sorry friend pls

Comment: @Dinesh I didn't see any ranges in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes i dont know to set range in that text boxs because that is appending by jquery so only i can ask help to friend

Comment: @Dinesh I've added an example of how the logic works. Someone else might be able to help you integrating it.

Comment: ok friend can u please explain how this logic works and where i need call this function please friend